# Pytest: monkeypatch not overruling environ variable

Tags: python, flask, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to test my Flask APP, but constants which are set inside the Config class using environment variables (`os.environ.get()`), aren't overruled by monkeypatching.

My config.py:

```
from os import environ, path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

basedir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
load_dotenv(path.join(basedir, '.env'))

class Config:
    """
    Set Flask configuration from environment variables, if present.
    """

    # General Config
    MY_VARIABLE = environ.get("SOME_ENV_VARIABLE", "somedefault")
```

My __init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config())
```

My tests/conftest.py

```
import pytest
from application import create_app

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("SOME_ENV_VARIABLE", "test")


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()
    # other setup can go here
    yield app
    # clean up / reset resources here
```

My tests/test_config.py:

```
class TestConfig:
    def test_config_values(self, app):
        assert app.config.get("MY_VARIABLE") == "test"
```

I keep getting  **AssertionError: assert 'somedefault' == 'test'**

If I add a method to the config class with a @property decorator, as described at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/config/#development-production, then everything seems to work ok, for that specific property. But for class constants, it doesn't.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be that `os.environ` simply gets imported before monkey patching happens?

Comment: You are right!! The `from application import create_app` made os.environ load earlier than monkeypatching the whole thing. It is fixed by simply moving the `from application import create_app` to the `app()` fixture. So that's great! But is there a cleaner option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are global variables which are instantiated from the environment at import time. The fixtures are applied after loading the test modules, so they kick in too late.

In other words, this is executed before:

```
MY_VARIABLE = environ.get("SOME_ENV_VARIABLE", "somedefault")
```

This is executed after:

```
monkeypatch.setenv("SOME_ENV_VARIABLE", "test")
```

There are several way to go around that:

1. don't execute `environ.get` at import time
2. monkeypatch `MY_VARIABLE` instead of `"SOME_ENV_VARIABLE"`
3. mock environment in `pytest_sessionstart` (but don't import the application from `conftest.py`, or it will still be too late)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation! I will get into that. Another question: do you have advice regarding resources which explain in more detail how the import time etc works within Python (the total lifecycle), perhaps? Besides this article https://www.benkuhn.net/importtime/ . Guess that would be nice extra study material :)

Comment: I don't have any material, but it is very simple in most cases: modules are imported when `import` is encountered :D. It is just a bit more special with `pytest`. It imports   `conftest`, executes some things there, then imports tests, then executes them (there may be other steps with plugins). All the rest is imported when there is an `import`.